# PowerShell - Error when querying AD if user enters credentials

Tags: .net, windows, powershell, active-directory, directoryservices

Trying to create a basic script for my IT helpdesk team that queries our AD to see if a computer's hostname is already on the domain. I want this to not require any modules so it can run on any Windows computer without additional software (because of this I am using `DirectoryServices`).

Also company coding policy prevents me from predefining credentials, so I want to make it user-defined. However, it seems that the script will run successfully only if they are predefined. Getting the below error if credentials are user-defined.

> Exception calling "FindAll" with "0" argument(s): "The user name or password is incorrect."

Below is a redacted version of what I have.

```
$username = read-host 'Enter username' 
$password = read-host 'Enter password' -AsSecureString
$hostname = hostname

Write-Host "Checking if $hostname is on the domain..."
$filter = "(&(ObjectCategory=computer)(Name=$hostname))"
$de = New-Object DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("LDAP://contoso.com/DC=contoso,DC=onmicrosoft,DC=com",$username,$password)
$ds = New-Object DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher $de
$ds.filter = $filter
$ds.findall() |
ForEach-Object -Begin {} -Process{$_.properties.item(“Name”)} -End { [string]$ds.FindAll().Count } | Out-Null
  if ($ds.FindAll().Count)
    {
        Write-Host "true"
    }
  else
    {
        Write-Host "false"
    }
```

Is it possible for the credentials to be user-defined or does it have to be predefined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`DirectoryEntry` constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directoryentry.-ctor?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0#system-directoryservices-directoryentry-ctor(system-string-system-string-system-string)) you're using requires the **`password` argument** to be a [**string**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string?view=net-6.0) instead of a [**secure string**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.securestring?view=net-6.0).

[`Read-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/read-host?view=powershell-7.2) when used with the `-AsSecureString` [outputs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/read-host?view=powershell-7.2#outputs) a `System.Security.SecureString` object. Converting it back to `string` and passing it as argument for the constructor should solve the problem:

```bash
$secpassw = Read-Host 'Enter password' -AsSecureString
$password = [System.Net.NetworkCredential]::new('', $secpassw).Password
```

It's also worth noting that since you're asking for Username and Password, [`Get-Credential`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/get-credential?view=powershell-7.2) might be a more elegant way for asking it and the same technique using [`NetworkCredential`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkcredential.-ctor?view=net-6.0#system-net-networkcredential-ctor(system-string-system-security-securestring)) to transform the secure string will work:

```bash
$cred  = Get-Credential
$passw = [System.Net.NetworkCredential]::new('', $cred.Password).Password
```

Comment: That worked! Appreciate the help

Comment: @shawneff_ happy to help :) I added an update with a maybe easier way to do it

Comment: @shawneff_ I think I should, why are you asking for username and password ? Any Domain user can query Active Directory without the need to specifying credentials. This is how Kerberos works. You can create your `DirectoryEntry` object using only the `LDAP` path and all should work fine for any Domain User.

Comment: The script I'm working on is meant to be run on a computer that's not on the domain. What I provided is a section of a domain joining script I'm working on and this was the only part I was having issues with. Apologies for not making this clear initially.

Comment: @shawneff_ no worries I was gonna answer the question anyways but was just curious about the use case, which makes sense now :)